# JSP WebApp - able to read but not update mysql table since switched over from Ubuntu to Win7

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I created an `inscription` form *(too large to post it here)* that stores the new user's credentials in `mysql` DB. It worked fine when i developed and tested it with my Ubuntu computer. The thing is, i exported the `war` file into my Win7 computer and even though it enables me to read from my DB table, it wont let me update it. To make a test, I've tried to create a new user with mySql command line and it works fine.
I also replaced my `Mysql J connector`.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'password' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at com.sdzee.dao.UtilisateurDaoImpl.creer(UtilisateurDaoImpl.java:86)


CREATE TABLE  bdd_sdzee.Utilisateur (
 id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 email VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
 passeword VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
 nom VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 date_inscription DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
 UNIQUE ( email )
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: And? What's your question? How are we supposed to help with so few details?

Comment: My question is: why, an application that works in Ubuntu, doesnt do so in Win7 when absolutely no code was modified. Sorry i dont know another way i could ask this question.

Comment: The database installation and configuration could be different, for example. If it "doesn't let you write", then you should have an exception. This exception comes with an error message and a stack trace. Reading this error message might help find what the problem is.

Comment: i've just updated my post by including the exception. I'll see what i can do to fix it. Thank you anyway for giving me a clue

Comment: Ok i see now that in Ubuntu i created mysql password column to accept jasypt encrypted passwords. The passwords, after being encrypted requires mores space in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error you need to increase the length of the **password** field in your database. Use one mysql client like HeidiSQL(http://www.heidisql.com/) to connect to your database in the Windows and change the length of your field to a bigger varchar or blob.

Comment: Thank you both JB Nizet and fmodos. I changed it to varchar(64) instead of 32

Comment: Wich means that Windows and Ubuntu do have different approaches to handle jasypt Encryption because i did use the same DB script to create my DB. Anyway I have learned something new.

Comment: Did you check in Ubuntu what was the varchar length created?

Comment: Wel, i created it with varchar(32) see my post above i just updated with the script which is the one i copy pasted in both MySQL DB of Windows and UBUNTU. I didnt modify anything. Like i said, i just copy and pasted exactly the same script.

Comment: But when i went visiting my Table in my Ubuntu's MsySQL i found out that MYSQL automatically adapted the value to varchar(52) instead of the initial 32 but it didnt do so in Windows computer.

Comment: hmm... that is interesting, thanks for your update